# Got and error when try to buy second item by In-App Purchase on swift?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

When i buy the first item with In-App Purchase it works fine without any problem.

But I got an Error on this when i tried to buy a second different item with In-App Purchase.

[image]

I already have this

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

    println("viewWillDisappear")

    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)

}
```

But still got an error.

So how can i fixed this Thanks!

Comment: May I ask where did you use SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver method please?

Comment: i use it on view didload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you're removing with,

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)
```

But not adding again with `addTransactionObserver` method.

Comment: Ah when i move SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self) to viewWillappear it works fine thanks!